# JPQL does not work on "Member" entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpql

I designed two entity "Member" and "Board" below to.

```
@Entity(name = "jpqlBoard")
public class Board {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String title;
}

@Entity(name = "jpqlMember")
public class Member {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String title;
}
```

And i created two JPQL to select tables on my Main method.

```
    String jpql = "select b from jpqlBoard b";
    System.out.println(
            em.createQuery(jpql, Board.class).getResultList()
    );

    jpql = "select m from jpqlMember m";
    System.out.println(
            em.createQuery(jpql, Member.class).getResultList()
    );
```

First JPQL to select Board works fine but other JPQL is not. Program print exception that unexpected token: Member. Does JPQL have no policy to support entity name contains some specific string such as "Member"? I cannot understand this exception message.

I attach my exception message that print during above code on runtime.

[image]

==========================================================================

I solve this problem. Member class and Board class was in the default package and I moved in to some package.

But why JPQL work incompletely in default package?

Comment: MEMBER is a JPQL keyword, as any JPA doc would tell you. That is why you can use "entityName" to use to refer to your entity so that you use a non-keyword. Since you set yours to "jpqlMember" then you should refer to the entity using that name

Comment: @NeilStockton tnx to answer. But it seems to be works fine in not default package but package created by me. Why JPQL works so incompletely?

Comment: "JPQL" doesn't do anything, its simply a language specification for queries. Your JPA implementation is what is doing (or not) the operation, so suggest that you turn your attention to Hibernate. That aside, your listing shows that you are NOT using "jpqlMember" in that case so it will fail. Also you do not need the entity class passing in as second argument ... that is the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why I think the Query on Member class returned error initially -

Your application did not scan the `@Entity` annotation on your `Member` class when you placed it in the `default` package. When you try to run the JPQL on `Member` class, `Hibernate` will look mapping for `jpqlMember` and it will throw the `QuerySyntaxException` as the class is not scanned and it will not be able to find one.

Later when your moved it to the same package where `Board` class exists, then it scanned your `Member` class successfully and your query got executed without any errors.

If you set the `packagesToScan="com.app.models"` property when configuring the `sessionFactory` bean, you need to make sure all the entities are present in that package.